# Can't figure out how to make the "x" actually close the "window" in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have recently been working on a minor project.
I have now run into a problem which i'm hoping that someone here might know something about :)

I am fairly new to reactjs in general so if it is poorly coded please let me know what i can improve on!

Basically i'm trying to render a window per say.
[Window picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsJK.png)

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import { Button, Row, Col } from "antd";
import "./App.css";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
import { WindowContext } from "./context/WindowProvider";

import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

import Home from "./components/Home";
import CreateWindow from "./components/CreateWindow";

function App() {
  const { windows, setWindows, addWindow, deleteWindow } = useContext(
    WindowContext
  );
  addWindow({
    id: "home",
    CW: CreateWindow({
      id: "home",
      src: <Home />,
      dimensions: {
        width: "50%",
        height: "70vh",
      },
    }),
  });
  return <div></div>;
}

export default App;
```

CreateWindow.js:

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  createRef,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col } from "antd";
import "../App.css";
import Draggable from "react-draggable"; // The default
import { WindowContext } from "../context/WindowProvider";
import { Resizable } from "re-resizable";

import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

function CreateWindow(data) {
  var new_window = (
    <div key={data.id} id={data.id}>
      <Draggable handle=".topBar">
        <div className="Window" style={data.dimensions}>
          <Row className="topBar">
            <Col className="itemp" span={23}></Col>

            <Col className="itemp closeButton" span={1}>
              <CloseOutlined color="red" onClick={() => {}} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          {data.src}
        </div>
      </Draggable>
    </div>
  );
  return new_window;
}

/* 
        </Resizable> */

export default CreateWindow;
```

RenderWindows.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { WindowContext } from "../context/WindowProvider";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function RenderWindows() {
  const { windows, addWindow } = useContext(WindowContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {windows.map((wi) => {
        return wi.CW;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default RenderWindows;
```

WindowProvider.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

export const WindowContext = createContext();

export const WindowProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [windows, setWindows] = useState([]);

  return (
    <WindowContext.Provider
      value={{
        windows,
        setWindows,
        addWindow: (window) => {
          var ae = false;
          windows.forEach((w) => {
            if (w.CW.props.id == window.CW.props.id) {
              ae = true;
            }
          });
          if (ae) return;

          setWindows([...windows, window]);
        },
        removeWindow: () => {},
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </WindowContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

But i really can't figure out a way to make it so you can actually use the close button to close it.
I've tried to use "useState" inside CreateWindow.js but since it isn't considered as a reactjs component it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you got it almost right. You have the close button and everything but don't do anything on it's on click event, speciafically this block of code:

```js
<Col className="itemp closeButton" span={1}>
    <CloseOutlined color="red" onClick={() => {} />
</Col>
```

As you can see your `onClick` is empty, that is where you want the code to close the window.

Next up, how would we implement the closing functionality? Personally, I would simply show and hide the window based on a boolean value, let us call it `windowOpened`.
For the sake of simplicity, I would say it should be implemented on your `CreateWindow.js` file.

Since this is something that we do want to trigger a re-render, we will want it to be a state, so using React hooks you will need the following line of code on your `CreateWindow` component:

```js
const [windowOpened, setWindowOpened] = useState(true)
```

Now... We need to actually set the `windowOpened` to false when you click the close button, so going back the block of code pointed out in the beginning of this answer, you will want to do:

```js
...
<Col className="itemp closeButton" span={1}>
    <CloseOutlined color="red" onClick={() => setWindowOpened(false) />
</Col>
...
```

Cool! Now you have the boolean setter hooked up, but you still need to make it actually do something. So, I would suggest to use it to decide whether or not we actually render the window, specifically on your component's return statement. Something like this:

```js
...
return windowOpened ? new_window : null
```

Comment: Well you see, i have already tried it... But since i cannot use react hooks when it is in a non component. Because i'm triggering the function inside a script to return the window code, then i store that inside the WindowProvider.js's state. And then i render that inside the RenderWindows.js
With that said. I cannot use states inside the CreateWindow.js because it isn't a componet. 
Thanks for you response tho!

Comment: @DeOnyx I am confused, why is it not considered a React component?

Comment: As you see i'm just running the "CreateWindow({...})" function
Not "<CreateWindow {...props}/>"